# Bulding OpenCV-2.3.x with Qt

Tags: qt, opencv

I'm having difficulties building OpenCV with Qt support on Ubuntu 10.04. 
I've tried all combinations:

[ OpenCV-2.3.0, OpenCV-2.3.1, OpenCV-2.2.0 ] x [QT-4.6.0 QT-4.7.4 and the version that comes with my distribution QT-4.6.2] to no avail.

The linker errors I get during the build process are these:

---

```
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `QMapData::createData(int)'                                
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `QVectorData::reallocate(QVectorData*, int, int, int)'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `QMapData::node_create(QMapData::Node**, int, int)'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `QListData::detach3()'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `QVectorData::free(QVectorData*, int)'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `qBadAlloc()'
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `QVectorData::allocate(int, int)'
```

---

I've googled for half a day, but nobody seems to have a similar problem...

I can build and use OpenCV without Qt enabled without any problems, using GCC-4.4.3.

In cmake(-gui), I only check "BUILD_EXAMPLES" and "WITH_QT". It doesn't make a difference whether I accept the initial "QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/qmake" or navigate it to the manually installed qt versions (sdk installer, I didn't build QT from source). The only things CMAKE doesn't find are some QT debug libraries, e.g. QT_DBUS_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND.

Does anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Thomas

**UPDATE:**
Well, I finally realized that CMAKE does not link with the required Qt libs during the build process (for example when building the examples). 
The quick and dirty hack was to add

```
-lQtGui -lQtCore -lQtOpenGL
```

to all CMAKE_XXX_LINKER_FLAGS ( in cmake-gui, select "grouped view", then those flags are in the "CMAKE" group ).

I still wonder though why the libs aren't linked automatically, and why hardly anyone seemed to have run into that problem. Maybe nobody builds OpenCV with QtGui?

Thomas

Comment: use apt-get to install from repository.